# how to put all in one HEAD_FETCH HEAD and ORIG_HEAD in git

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

I'm a newbie using Git and more concretely egit into eclipse.

I am trying to merge all commits into one branch but what I get is that I cannot do that because cherry-pick does not allow two different parents.

I don't know what went wrong after fetching from my remote. In history tree I can see that Origin/Master and FETCH_HEAD seem to be lost somewhere in the past. How can I get those changes to be merged into the master branch to keep on going?

[image: history tree]

Answer (score 0):

First, cherry-picking does not do merging! It takes changesets and applies them — as patches, so no ancestry information is recorded.

Second, what does the phrase "to merge all commits into one branch" mean? You can merge one or more branches into another, not specific commits, let alone "all" commits.

So what do you really want to do? Merge `origin/master` into `master`? Then just

```
$ git checkout master
$ git merge origin/master
```

At this point you might get conflicts; in that case you'll need to resolve each of them (use `git status` to see which paths are in conflicting state; use `git add` after resolving conflicts in a particular file to stage its updated contents for the new commit thus marking the conflicts for that file as resolved), then `git commit` the result.

Do not try to mess with `FETCH_HEAD` by hand — it's a plumbing-level reference mostly intended for `git pull` to communicate the results of `git fetch` it calls to `git merge` it calls afterwards.

Comment: Anyone know how to do these from inside eclipse?